# use SQL data selected from html dropdown list

Tags: php, html, sql

NEWBIE ALERT
Ive been reading for hours but cannot see how to do what I want. I have an SQL DB with a list of medication and dosages etc. Im trying to create an 'edit' page so i can select the medication from a dropdown list(this appears to work), and edit certain parts of it(size, box quantity, doseage etc.

the problem is i cant get the selected medication item(from dropdown) to become a variable or if neccessary, forward to a 2nd PHP page.
Ive left a couple of attempted edits in there but they caused errors (**TRIED NOT WORK**)
As it is, It is loading editmed.php to load my edit page on submit. (not sure if this is the best way of doing it).

Any help would be great thanks

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
     </head>
    <body>

    <div class="header">
    <h1>Edit Medication Item</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="topnav">
    <a href="indexhl.php">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="edit.php">Edit Medication</a>
    <a href="presc_coll.php">Prescription Collection</a>
    <a href="add-new.php">Add New Medication</a>
    <a href="pillbox.php">Pillbox refill</a>
    <a href="individualtopup.php">Individual refill</a>
    </div>

    <?php
    // server connect
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost:port", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "prescription") 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    // select medication name field from db
    echo "<p><b><U><i><p style='color:red'>Select Medication</I></U></p><p style='color:black'></b></p>";
    $sqlSelect="select Medication from general";
    $result = $mysqli -> query ($sqlSelect);
    //$medselect=$result['Medication'];**TRIED NOT WORK** 

    echo "<form action='editmed.php'>";
    echo "<select id=`Medication` name=`medselect`>";  

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['Medication'] . "'>" . $row['Medication'] . "</option>";
    }
    //$medselect=$result['Medication'];**TRIED NOT WORK**


    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'>";
    // echo "<input type='submit' value='<$medselect>' name='medselect'/>" ; **TRIED NOT WORK**

    echo "</form>" ; 
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";

    ?> 

    </body>

    </html>
```

editmed.php >

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="global.css">
    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="header">

    <h1>Edit Medication Item</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="topnav">
    <a href="indexhl.php">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="edit.php">Edit Medication</a>
    <a href="presc_coll.php">Prescription Collection</a>
    <a href="add-new.php">Add New Medication</a>
    <a href="pillbox.php">Pillbox refill</a>
    <a href="individualtopup.php">Individual refill</a>
    </div>


    <?php

    // server connect
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost:port", "user", "password", 
    "prescription") 
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');

    // $sql = "SELECT ID, Medication, dosagedaily, Box_Size, Boxed_remain, 
    grandtotal, last_collected, Dosage, countdown FROM general where 
    `Medication` = $medselect";

    $sql = "SELECT ID, Medication, dosagedaily, Box_Size, Boxed_remain, 
    grandtotal, last_collected, Dosage, countdown FROM general where 
    `Medication` = 'Esomeprazole 40mg'";
 
 
    // you check sql and link true
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Index</th>";
            echo "<th>Medication</th>";
            echo "<th>Daily Dosage</th>";
            echo "<th>Box Size</th>" ;
            echo "<th>Boxed Remaining</th>" ;
            echo "<th>Grand Total</th>";
            echo "<th>Last presc collection</th>";
            echo "<th>Dosage</th>";
            echo "<th>Pills Remaining</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
            
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Medication'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['dosagedaily'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Box_Size'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Boxed_remain'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['grandtotal'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['last_collected'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Dosage'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['countdown'] . "</td>";
            
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        // Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    } else{
        echo "No records matching your query were found.";
    }
    } 
    else{
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
 
    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);
```

i dont know how to assign the variables from the input form, thats where my issue is.If i get a variable assigned then i can create the actual editing part.

Comment: When you get into `editmed.php`, what is in your `$_GET` array? You should have two variables, your `medselect` dropdown, and your submit button. Your post has back-ticks instead of single quotes, I'm not sure if that makes any difference or whether they're in your actual code.

Comment: HI, i have edited to include the editmed.php now, the variable assignment is the part i dont know how to do. If i can get a variable attached to it then i can do the editing part!!

Comment: I find it very difficult to understand the details of this. Often to edit data in a database you query the database and put the data into the value attribute of an input element of an HTML form. The user can see this and if they want change it. Then when they submit the form the PHP script updates the database with the new data. Is that basically what you are doing or have I missed the whole point?

Comment: This is basically what im doing but i need to create a query using the data selected in the dropdown list. i know this should be able to have a variable assigned to selection but i cant figure out how. if i use a static assignment in editmed.php then it works(`Medication` = 'Esomeprazole 40mg'). I need this to be whatever the selection from the dropdown is.

Comment: If you add a line into the start of your editmed code that is `var_dump($_GET)` followed by `exit()`, you should see what's in the form. In there, you should see your drop-down selection, and you'll know how to access it for your query. But you really should select the id of the med, not the description.